# Swift - Populating Table Rows

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am populating a table with a list of names fetched from the backend (as usernames and then as names of friends).

The arrays are showing that all content is there (it should contain 2 records) but for some reason, I am doing something silly that is leading to only one record (single row) being displayed in the table view.

I personally believe that this is an error due to implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        let cellIdentifier = "cell"

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? FriendsCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = FriendsCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

        // Configure the cell to show name of friend
        print("Index Row: \(indexPath.row)")
        cell!.name.text = self.friendsInfoListArray[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String


        return cell
    }
```

Can someone spot where is it going wrong? as stated, there are two records in the array but only one is being displayed.

thanks

Update:

code for reloadTable:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

        self.loadFriendsUsernames({ (result)->Void in
            if(result.count > 0)
            {
                self.loadFriendsInfo({ (result)->Void in
                      if(result.count > 0)
                      {
                        print(self.friendsInfoListArray)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        print("Success Loading Friends Info Array")
                      }else{
                       print("Error Loading Friends Info Array")
                      }
                })
            }else{
                print("Error Loading Friends Usernames Array")
            }

        })


        let query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo: currentUser!["appUsername"])
        // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
        // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
        if self.objects!.count == 0 {
            query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
        }

        return query
    }
```

Comment: In your numberOfRowsInSection method, what value are you returning? Is it the count of the array, or just 1.

Comment: Have you implemented the numberOfRowsInSection function?

Comment: @totiG good catch implemented but left it blank. I added to it what was needed, but now getting another error that says "NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"

Comment: That would likely be because the numberOfRows section returns more rows than you have in your array. Is your numberOfRows implementation set to: return friendsInfoListArray.count

Comment: @totiG yes indeed it is....better way?

Comment: That is the correct way. Where you are setting the cell!.name.text = ... set it to = indexPath.row (so the text will just write out the row index). If that works, then it is likely one of your rows does not contain a ["name"]

Comment: @totiG did that and still the same error coming....

Comment: Initially your viewController would have the friendsInfoListArray as an empty array with no items in it. When your data call to get the friends from the server has returned, and you have set the friendsInfoListArray (so that it now contains 2 items) - do you call tableView.reloadData()? And if you do, are you possibly changing the friendsInfoListArray again?

Comment: no I don't call it actually....should I call it after the call that sets friendsInfoListArray?

Comment: @totiG just did....I updated the code in original post to show the call....but it didn't help...same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100575/discussion-between-totig-and-ksa-coder).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are getting your friend list in viewDiDLoad: method.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    self.loadFriendsUsernames({ (result)->Void in
        if(result.count > 0)
        {
            self.loadFriendsInfo({ (result)->Void in
                  if(result.count > 0)
                  {
                    print(self.friendsInfoListArray)
                    self.friendsInfoListArray = result
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    print("Success Loading Friends Info Array")
                  }else{
                   print("Error Loading Friends Info Array")
                  }
            })
        }else{
            print("Error Loading Friends Usernames Array")
        }

    })


    let query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo: currentUser!["appUsername"])
    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if self.objects!.count == 0 {
        query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
    }

    return query
}


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return self.friendsInfoListArray.count;

    }
```

Comment: I did that but as stated in above comment, I am getting following error as result: "NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"

Comment: Make sure your friendsInfoListArray should be created with all possible objects and then reload table.

Comment: reloadTable? can you outline what that means? not familiar with it sorry

Comment: Edit answer with proper implementation.

Comment: I am using Parse's PFQueryTableViewController for my view controller. SO there is a method called queryForTable and there I am loading both arrays before loading data to table.

Comment: Add self.friendsInfoListArray = result to update friendsInfoListArray from result.

Comment: Is this to make sure the content of the array is available and not empty?

Comment: I mean just update your friend list array which are using to populate tableview should be updated from query result.

Comment: when I print indexPath.row inside the cellForRow method, I get 0 and the the count of the friendsInfoArray count is showing 2

Answer (score 0):

After long trying, I found the solution that worked for me:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
          let query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)
        self.loadFriendsUsernames({ (result)->Void in
            if(result.count > 0)
            {
                self.loadFriendsInfo({ (result)->Void in
                      if(result.count > 0)
                      {
                        print(self.friendsInfoListArray)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                         let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo: currentUser!["appUsername"])
        // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
        // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
        if self.objects!.count == 0 {
            query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
        }

                        print("Success Loading Friends Info Array")
                      }else{
                       print("Error Loading Friends Info Array")
                      }
                })
            }else{
                print("Error Loading Friends Usernames Array")
            }

        })




        return query
    }
```